# Spring Security: configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)

Tags: spring, spring-security, h2

I have an entity `User` with attributes:

- `id`
- `username`
- `password`
- `firstname`
- `lastname`
- `userrole`

Attribute `userrole` is type of `enum` and no `Set`, so 1 userrole/user.

Now I want to do a JDBC authentication.

For now I have:

```
auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password from user where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, userrole from user where username=?");
```

But this doesn't work.

How should the query in `.usersByUsernameQuery("...")` and `.authoritiesByUsernameQuery("...");` be formulated?

Error message:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Not allowed value "3" for parameter "columnIndex"
>   Invalid value "3" for parameter "columnIndex" [90008-192]
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.getInvalidValueException(DbException.java:228) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.checkColumnIndex(JdbcResultSet.java:3172) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.get(JdbcResultSet.java:3200) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getBoolean(JdbcResultSet.java:541) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
>           at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$1.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:223) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$1.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:218) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           ... 65 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query for the user needs 3 parameters, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-jdbc-user-service):

> - **users-by-username-query** An SQL statement to query a username, password, and enabled status given a username. The default is
>
> ```
> select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?
> ```